# How can I extend the WooCommerce WC_Cart class and override select methods?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can't even get started; an empty class save for the construct which calls the parent construct, when I try adding anything to the cart, ajax says ok view cart, but the cart always remains empty. Same when I copy the entire WC_Cart contents into my class. I have a plugin with a class that sets `$GLOBALS['woocommerce']->cart = new WC_Custom_Cart();` once wp_loaded.

```
class WooCustom {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, 'wp_loaded' ) );
    }

    function wp_loaded() {
        self::woocustom_cart_init();
    }

    private function woocustom_cart_init() {
        if ( is_main_site( get_current_blog_id() ) ) {
            if ( ! is_admin() || defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
                require_once( 'classes/wc-custom-cart.php' );
                $GLOBALS['woocommerce']->cart = new WC_Custom_Cart();
            }
        }
    }
}

class WC_Custom_Cart extends WC_Cart {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Thank you all for your consideration and I apologize for my vague pleading and inquiry.

What I need first of all is in the cart to simply eradicate all pricing/fee totals. (OK to display custom fields Cost and MSRP, but no charge.) 
Also variable products need to be able to be added to the cart like simple products, sans variations selection, because the entire product is to be imported with all of its variations.

Comment: This is just too broad, so you have very small chances to get an answer. I think that there is other ways using existing related hooks and overriding related woocommerce templates…

Comment: It's a good broad question. But please refine it to a more focused question, including what you've tried. Saying "I can't even get started" is going to turn off the general community. So start.

Comment: Copy the question here.